# Unable to open iTunes

Tags: windows-10, itunes, administrator

Bit of background:

Me: Domain Admin

User: User

User cannot open iTunes at all. When he tries, one of two things happen: If "Run as Administrator" is enabled in compatibility settings, then it will prompt for credentials, which he does not have. If it is not enabled, the UAC icon remains in the corner of the iTunes logo, and nothing happens upon double click. This is the same for my admin account. Checking task manager, whenever iTunes is double clicked, iTunes.exe takes a spot in task manager, but nothing happens still unless ran with administrator credentials. I tried with my regular domain account, same thing happens.

I have reinstalled older versions, newest version, followed all uninstall guides for correct order, checked permissions on the application and on the Music folder, made sure the computer was verified, checked event log. Disabling UAC or providing admin credentials is obviously not an option. I tried a specific program UAC disabling method using Compatibility Administrator, but that only works if the program actually tries to start.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Update: The issue seems to be computer specific, I will have to test another persons computer, but no other users in the organization have had this problem, and with the amount of company iPhones we have, we would have heard something from another user by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was BTTray.exe. Closing the process and trying to open iTunes allowed it to open, also disabled in startup and tested with a reboot and multiple user accounts. Interestingly, closing that process doesn't disable Bluetooth on the machine, and it also does not get rid of the system tray icon. Somebody else said that this occurred for them after the Windows 10 Creators Update.

But, it is fixed. Hopefully people can see this and save some time, unlike me.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% certain this is the same as your problem, but I once had a similar issue, and found that I didn't have 'Bonjour' installed - it's needed to detect iOS devices I believe, but in my case *not* having it installed meant iTunes wouldn't open.

You can check from your main add/remove programs - just an idea to try!

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, Bonjour is indeed installed though. I should have been more clear, the program does open with Admin credentials, but it only prompts for them if the setting is enabled in compatibility administrator or if you  right click > Run as Admin. It opens and it still has his login information cached. I getting the feeling it might have been a windows or iTunes update.